# How do i use pointer as parameter

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, uint64, conversion-specifier

I write something to get famliar with pointer.

```
    void print_line(int64_t number, char *string)
{
    (void)number;
    (void)string;

    printf("%d %s \n", number, *string);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    print_line(42, "Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the outcome to be 42 and "Hello World!". However it is 42 (null).
I assume that i used pointer in a wrong way.
Where was my mistake? Why is the address empty?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you dereferencing the pointer if you want to print the entire string? That's not what you should be passing to `printf` when using the `%s` specifier

Comment: What’s with lines 3 and 4? I seem to be seeing a lot of that lately.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Garbage. They should be deleted. In other circumstances, it could be used to avoid "unused" warnings.

Comment: I know that it is meaningless. If you have unused arguments, don’t specify a name, just the type. Is that really what people are doing nowdays? (Because it’s weird, IMHO.)

Comment: Use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` in case you use gcc.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter has the type `int64_t`

```
void print_line(int64_t number, char *string)
```

On the other hand, the conversion specifier `%d` serves to output numbers of the type `int`. So by this reason this call

```
printf("%d %s \n", number, *string);
```

is already incorrect and invokes undefined behavior because a wrong conversion specifier is used with an object of the type `int64_t`.

You could use the conversion specifier `%d` in the call of `printf` if the first parameter of your function had the type `int` or `unsigned int` and in the last case if the value of the type `unsigned int` is representable in the type `int`.

Moreover the conversion specifier `%s` expects a pointer of the type `char *` while you passed the expression `*string` that has the type `char`.

What you need is to include the header `<inttypes.h>`

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

and change the call of `printf` like

```
printf( "%" PRId64 " %s\n", number, string );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void print_line( int64_t number, const char *string )
{
    printf( "%" PRId64 " %s\n", number, string );
}

int main(void) 
{
    print_line( 42, "Hello World!" );
        
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
42 Hello World!
```

Comment: Since I'm very new in c, i really know few about everything. Your comment helps a lot!

Comment: @tcx If the answer was useful you can select the best answer. In this case your reputation will be increased.:)

Answer (score 0):

`printf %s` expects a pointer to the first character of a string. That's what `string` is.

```c
printf("%d %s\n", number, *string);
```

should be

```c
printf("%d %s\n", number, string);
```

Make sure to enable your compiler's warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pendatic` using gcc and glang).

Comment: I also recommend `-pedantic-errors` just to make you make things clean (so, you get `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`). When using MSVC it should be `/W4`.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I do use `-pendatic`. I don't know why I left it out.